# How to implement ' Call me ' function in Firebase Phone Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Phone number authentication for authenticate my users. (Android)
Everything is fine, but I don't know how to call the User's phone for the verification Code instead of sending a SMS message. Sometimes SMS never reaches the device.  So 'Call Me' button helps there. 
So how to implement that feature in Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it works only with text messages.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Firebase Auth doesn't have the call me feature. Maybe you can try 
CheckMobi, which has the feature you are asking for.
https://www.checkmobi.com/#/SmsProduct